# Scheme Pairs output

Tags: scheme, racket

Trying to produce an output of pairs that would look like (1 1) (1 2) (1 3) (2 2) (2 3) (3 3), if taking the first 6 elements of a stream.  (The first 6 have 3 columns and it should print the pairs beginning with 1 and then 2 and then 3.)  The code I have is:

```
(define (pairs s t)
  (cons-stream (cons (stream-car s) (stream-car t))
               (cons-stream
                (stream-map (lambda (x) (cons (stream-car s) x))
                            (stream-cdr t))
                (pairs (stream-cdr t) (stream-cdr s)))))
```

And if I run

```
(take 6 (pairs integers integers))
```

where take and integers are defined as follows:

```
(define (take n s)  
  (if (= n 0)
      '()
      (cons (stream-car s) (take (- n 1) (stream-cdr s)))))

(define integers (cons-stream 1 (add-streams ones integers)))
```

The result I get is:

```
((1 . 1)
 ((1 . 2) . #<promise>)
 (2 . 2)
 ((2 . 3) . #<promise>)
 (3 . 3)
 ((3 . 4) . #<promise>))
```

Comment: what would `(take 200 (pairs integers integers))` produce? should `(1 4)`, `(1 5)`, `(1 15)` etc. appear there? what is "three columns"?

Comment: this question does not have a satisfactory answer at its "duplicate"; the closing message below says "If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question" but this is ***exactly*** what the OP did ***here***. Vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

In Scheme,

```
(define (interleaved-pairs xs ys . args)
  (let ((x (stream-car xs))
        (ac (if (null? args) () (car args))))
    (stream-append 
      (stream-map stream-car (list->stream (reverse ac)))
      (stream-cons (list x (stream-car ys))
        (interleaved-pairs 
          (stream-cdr xs)
          (stream-cdr ys)
          (cons
            (stream-map (lambda(y)(list x y)) (stream-cdr ys))
            (map stream-cdr ac)))))))
```

This should produce results in the order you wanted: `(1 1) (1 2) (2 2) (1 3) (2 3) (3 3) (1 4) ...`.

You tagged this as racket also. As far as I can see in [the Racket documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html), it has `stream-first` in place of `stream-car`, etc. For some reason it doesn't seem to have `list->stream`, which can be defined quite straightforwardly with the `apply` and `stream` functions.

---

Here it is in [a shorter notation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info).

```hs
ipairs xs ys = g xs ys []  where
  g (x:xs) (y:ys) ac = map head (reverse ac) ++ (x,y) : 
                         g xs ys (map ((,) x) ys : map tail ac)
```